# IE vtt track background color

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, webvtt, vtt

Why does IE load the .vtt without a black background but chromes does, need IE to be normal and have the black background have searched around to no prevail.

Any help with this issue will be greatly appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
 <video [src]='videoURL' controls (ended)="onVideoEnd($event)" [style.maxHeight]="screen.data.height">
    <track label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" [src]="screen.data.ccs" default
 </video>
```

**CSS**

```
video {
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 47%;
    width: auto;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

video:fullscreen{
    transform: translate(0%, 0%);
}
```

**Chrome:**
[image: Chrome:]

**IE:**
[image: IE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebVTT_API), you can style the cue

```
video::cue {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, dimgray, lightgray);
  color: papayawhip;
}

video::cue(b) {
  color: peachpuff;

}
```

From memory, this works in IE.

Comment: This worked in Chrome but it didn't work in IE I also tried to implement the style in the vtt file itself and that didn't work in ether browser.

Comment: @DylanAnlezark have a look at the [examples](https://www.w3.org/TR/webvtt1/#introduction-other-features) here, mostly 6. This might work in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the CSS style, I guess perhaps you are using the ::cue CSS pseudo-element to set the background color. From [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::cue), we can find that the IE browser doesn't support this property. So, it will not display the background color in IE browser.

I suggest you could try to remove the background color, so that in Chrome and IE browser, they will have the same style (without background color).